# Raspberry Pi 3: Kernel Panic 179.2

Tags: pi-3, boot, boot-issues

Total newb to Raspberries here, never touched Linux either.

I've just gotten an Rpi 3 [with 3.5" LCD](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Raspberry-Pi-3-Model-B-Board-3-5-TFT-LCD-8GB-TF-Card-2-5A/32794210339.html) and installed 
[RASPBIAN JESSIE WITH PIXEL](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) via Etcher to 8 GB card following the instructions on the website. Etcher said that some issues are possible, but burning went kinda fine.

However the LCD just shows a white screen. It didn't respond to my keyboard or mouse activity. Connected it to a TV via HDMI, I get `Kernel Panic: VFS : Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (179,2).`

I googled that error, but nothing seems to be of help to me.

SD card is 8 GB but on my PC it shows 20 out of 40.3 MB available, idk if it's normal or not.

EDIT: So, I formated my SD, checked it for corrupted sectors and problems (didn't find any) and Etcher'ed it again. Guess what? Same problem, this time, I did save the message from Etcher:

> The write has been completed successfully but Etcher detected potential corruption issues when reading the image back from the drive. Please consider writing the image to a different drive.

I don't have any other SD's atm and corrupting another one doesn't sound super cool to me tbh. I hope someone had simillar issue and could help me with mine.

Comment: *"Etcher said that some issues are possible"* -> Perhaps you want to edit in some details about that, because I would say burning did not go fine.   Beware you may not be able to get that LCD screen to work if it requires drivers that are not included in stock Raspbian.  [Caveat emptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor), unfortunately.

Comment: *"corrupting another one doesn't sound super cool to me"* -> Corruption is  not permanent physical damage, although it may be **caused** by it.  In other words, burning an image to a card, whether it works or not, does not damage the card.  However, if the card is already damaged or defective, it may cause corruption.

Comment: Ok then, I'll get another card and try again. I'll update the post with Round 3 whenever I'll get a new card. Thank you for your time.

Comment: "burning went kinda fine" - There's no such thing as *kinda fine* as far as data consistency is concerned. Either the data is corrupted, or it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that the second partition on the card (`179,2`) either does not exist or is not formatted properly.

> on my PC it shows 20 out of 40.3 MB available, idk if it's normal or not

Yes, because Windows machines cannot read [ext4 filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4), at least not without third party tools.  Unfortunately, this means there is no way to tell, using such a machine, whether there is a second partition and if it is formatted correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember what Etcher said to me. Ok, I think I'll figure out what to do with LCD later, because it seems to be working fine for other users.  
Could you tell me, if it's a good idea to format my SD card and try again? Is it normal for not-booting Rp3 not to respond to keaboard?

Comment: Yes.  There's nothing much you could do if it did respond anyway.  There's no root filesystem.  You might as well try to reburn the card (and note the errors, if any, this time).  I recommend you *don't* bother with NOOBS, BTW (I think you wrote something about that in the original question which I pruned) -- it does not seem to make life easier for anyone.

Comment: Use the TV, with the keyboard plugged in, the first time you boot.  It could be that something got screwed up the first time before if there was nothing on the LCD but the system did boot properly and you were hitting keys, because initially there's some configuration options you can go through.  Also, if it did boot then and you had to pull the plug, the card might have been corrupted which could explain the problem.

Comment: Thank you, it's time for Round 2 then. I'll do my best and will edit the post with the results.

Comment: Ok, updated with Round 2 results.